# Redirect via Api Token doesent work within Flask App after setting reverse Proxy

Tags: python, apache, flask, flask-restful

I have a problem with my Flask App. I have a User Authentication , that checks if the User is authenticated and then redirectes to the /index . Somehow that doesent work.

I´d be very grateful for any suggestions.

```
@api.route('/login/jwt/', methods=['POST'])
class JWTLogin(Resource):
    def post(self):
        try:
            data = request.form

            if not data:
                data = request.json

            if not data:
                return {
                           'message': 'username or password is missing',
                           "data": None,
                           'success': False
                       }, 400
            # validate input
            user = Users.query.filter_by(username=data.get('username')).first()
            if user and verify_pass(data.get('password'), user.password):
                try:

                    # Empty or null Token
                    if not user.api_token or user.api_token == '':
                        user.api_token = generate_token(user.id)
                        user.api_token_ts = int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
                        db.session.commit()

                    # token should expire after 24 hrs
                    return {
                        "message": "Successfully fetched auth token",
                        "success": True,
                        "data": user.api_token
                    }
                except Exception as e:
                    return {
                               "error": "Something went wrong",
                               "success": False,
                               "message": str(e)
                           }, 500
            return {
                       'message': 'username or password is wrong',
                       'success': False
                   }, 403
        except Exception as e:
            return {
                       "error": "Something went wrong",
                       "success": False,
                       "message": str(e)
                   }, 500







@blueprint.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm(request.form)

    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        # read form data
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        # Locate user
        user = Users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

        # Check the password
        if user and verify_pass(password, user.password):
            login_user(user)
            logging.debug(
            colorama.Fore.GREEN + 'Redirecting to authentication_blueprint.route_default' + colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
            logging.debug(
            colorama.Fore.GREEN + f'{current_user}' + colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
            return redirect(url_for('authentication_blueprint.route_default'))

        logging.debug(
            colorama.Fore.RED + 'LOGIN Failed' + colorama.Style.RESET_ALL
        )
        # Something (user or pass) is not ok
        return render_template('accounts/login.html',
                               msg='Wrong user or password',
                               form=login_form)

    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        logging.debug(
            colorama.Fore.GREEN + 'User is already authenticated. Redirecting to home_blueprint.index' + colorama.Style.RESET_ALL
        )
        return redirect(url_for('home_blueprint.index'))
    else:
        logging.debug(
            colorama.Fore.RED + 'Useris not authenticated.back to login' + colorama.Style.RESET_ALL
        )
        return render_template('accounts/login.html',
                               form=login_form)
```

The fetch is being done in the html.

```
   fetch('/gandalf/login/jwt/', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((res) => {

                    //console.log('Token: ' + res.data);

                    // store token in localStorage
                    asyncLocalStorage.setItem('token', res.data).then(result => {
                        e.target.submit()
                    })

                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        }
```

And this is my Server Console Output :

```
023-05-16 17:25:36,989 127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2023 17:25:36] "POST /gandalf/login/jwt/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2023-05-16 17:25:37,102 Redirecting to authentication_blueprint.route_default
2023-05-16 17:25:37,102 Damon doe
2023-05-16 17:25:37,103 127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2023 17:25:37] "POST /gandalf/login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2023-05-16 17:25:37,149 127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2023 17:25:37] "GET /gandalf/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2023-05-16 17:25:37,181 Useris not authenticated.back to login
2023-05-16 17:25:37,184 127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2023 17:25:37] "GET /gandalf/login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I was wondering if this could have been caused by my Reverse Proxy that is using the gandalf Prefix ?

thank you